# Site name in Google search results for multi-language websites

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Using Schema.org, I can set the name for my website so it’s visible in Google Search: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/site-name

Example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
       "@type" : "WebSite",
       "name" : "Your WebSite Name",
       "alternateName" : "An alternative name for your WebSite",
       "url" : "http://www.your-site.com"
    }
    </script>
```

What if I have multi-language website? 5 languages → 5 index pages, e.g.: `http://www.example.com/en/`

Is it right to set different URLs for each language with different website names? I cannot find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you use different paths (`…/en/` + `…/de/`), different subdomains (`en.example.com` + `de.example.com`) or different domains (`example.com` + `example.net`), you have different (albeit translated) websites.

So use a separate [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) item for each of your sites.

#### Example (using RDFa)

On `http://example.com/en/`, you could specify:

```
<head typeof="schema:WebSite">
  <title property="schema:name">Example</title>
  <link property="schema:url" rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/en/" />
</head>
```

And on `http://example.com/de/`, you could specify:

```
<head typeof="schema:WebSite">
  <title property="schema:name">Beispiel</title>
  <link property="schema:url" rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/de/" />
</head>
```

Comment: One question: What can I do if, for example, Russian and Ukrainian version of the website has the same name? Google: Be unique to your site—not used by some other site. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Zhenya: As this is a SEO advice question (technically, there’s nothing wrong with multiple sites having the same name), it’s off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You could head to [webmasters.se] for it.