# Schema.org for website with multiple languages: filling Corporation and WebSite things right

Tags: localization, multilingual, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I'm working on a multiple-language website and I'm preparing Schema.org markups using JSON-LD. Important detail: this website uses subdirectories for languages. Let's consider 2 languages:

- English: `https://www.example.com/`
- French: `https://www.example.com/fr/`

I want to put `Corporation` and `WebSite` things on all localized HP. Everything goes fine but for `@id`, `url` and `inLanguage` properties: I don't quite know what I should fill.

For `Corporation`, I think I got it right: I'm going to use on all pages default url and base my `@id` on it:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Corporation",
    "@id": "https://www.example.com/#organization",
    "name": "Example",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/",
...
```

But what would be the best move for `WebSite` properties, on my French HP? 
Technically speaking, `/fr/` subfolder is part of the `example.com/` domain. But then, `@id`, `inLanguage` and `url` are not telling my website is also available for French-speakers.

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "@id": "https://www.example.com/#website",   // should this be "https://www.example.com/fr/#website" ?
    "name": "Example",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/",   // should this be "https://www.example.com/fr/" ?
    "inLanguage": "en",   // should this be "fr" ?
...
```

I searched a lot about this and found nothing on this particular matter.
Does anyone have any experience on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two [different (albeit translated)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30462273/1591669) websites. It shouldn’t matter that they share the same domain/hostname.

Each website should get its own `WebSite` item, with its own `@id`, `url`, and `inLanguage` values, while they would refer to the same `Corporation` item.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "@id": "https://www.example.com/#website",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "inLanguage": "en",
  "publisher": {"@id": "https://www.example.com/#organization"}
}
```

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "@id": "https://www.example.com/fr/#website",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/fr/",
  "inLanguage": "fr",
  "publisher": {"@id": "https://www.example.com/#organization"}
}
```

If the websites are primarily translations, you could use [`workTranslation`](http://schema.org/workTranslation)/[`translationOfWork`](http://schema.org/translationOfWork) to link the `WebSite` items.

```json
"workTranslation": {"@id": "https://www.example.com/fr/#website"}
```

```json
"translationOfWork": {"@id": "https://www.example.com/#website"}
```

(This is a good case to see why the `WebSite` items should have different `@id` values, because otherwise you couldn’t refer to their translations like that. Using the `url` value instead of the `@id` value wouldn’t be a good idea, because this URI [typically represents the homepage, not the whole website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099116/1591669).)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I have learnt something very interesting thanks to your help. As you wrote, @id is very powerful.